# Reading data from the serial port USB bar-code scanner

Tags: usb, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to read the Barcode via the serial port but the scanner isn't showing up as a com port.

The scanner works fine as a keyboard, but when I scan the code to set it to 'serial' nothing.

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: @stresscool  Windows 7, no disk\driver came with the Scanner and the Driver was installed automatically as it was plugged in....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install a software provided by your device vendor for com port emulation,just search for this in vendor portal.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion..Barcode scanner of USB-type is an USB HID Keyboard.

Not USB CDC profile(Virtual COM) but USB HID profile.

Therefore, it is recognized as a USB keyboard.

You must change RS232 cable for barcode (RJ45-10pin to DSUB9 Cable).

And you must check your barcode scanner can support RS232.